# when dowlnoading files why the names on the hard disk are test01 then test11 test21 test31 test41 test51 test61 and not test1 test2 test3?

Tags: c#, winforms

The files names are incorrect i want to give to each file name a number and increasing the numbers by one.

at the top

```
private int counter = 0;
```

when downloading and saving the files

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    await DownloadFiles(downloadLinks[i], testFolder + "\\test" + counter + 1.ToString() + ".gif");
    counter++;
}
```

The result is

> test01 test11 test21 test31 test41 test51 test61

and i want the files names to be

> test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6

Comment: Your expectation seems to be that `counter + 1.ToString()` is evaluated as `(counter + 1).ToString()` and not `counter + (1.ToString())`.  One thing to consider, though, is how the compiler would know that's what you want without explicitly telling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are converting 1 to string (that way you cannot add it to the counter), put them in braces or it is much cleaner to add them before you are placing it as an argument.

```
int counter = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    await DownloadFiles(downloadLinks[i], testFolder + "\\test" + (counter + 1) + ".gif");
    counter++;
}
```

alternatively you could use `Path.Combine()` and string interpolation, to make it much cleaner:

```
int counter = 0;
    
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    await DownloadFiles(downloadLinks[i], Path.Combine(testFolder, $"test{counter + 1}.gif"));
    counter++;
}
```